# React Native Navigation To External Tab Within BottomTabBar Screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an issue where I do not know how to navigate from a screen in a bottom tab bar that looks like this:

```
default: createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: HomeScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={24} color={tintColor} />
          }
        },
        Message: {
          screen: MessageScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name="ios-chatboxes" size={24} color={tintColor} />,
            OtherUser: { screen: OtherUserScreen }
          }
        },
        Post: {
          screen: PostScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name="ios-add-circle" size={48} color={"#4cdd75"} style={{
              shadowColor: "#4cdd75",
              shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 0
              },
              shadowRadius: 10,
              shadowOpacity: 0.3
            }} />
          }
        },
        Notification: {
          screen: NotificationScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name="ios-notifications" size={24} color={tintColor} />
          }
        },
        Profile: {
          screen: ProfileScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={24} color={tintColor} />
          }
        }
      }
```

With the createSwitchNavigator component looking like this:

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: LoadingScreen,
      App: AppContainer,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      OtherUser: OtherUserScreen
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Loading'
    }
  )
);
```

The AppContainer is the bottom tab navigator screen setup.
Additionally, My navigation from within my message screen looks like this:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
...
onPress={() => navigate('OtherUser')}
```

From this message screen I want to navigate to the OtherUser screen so that the bottom tab navigator is still shown. Currently, the navigation navigates to the OtherUser screen, but the bottom tab navigator dissapears. And when I try to use the back button code navigation in my OtherUser Screen that looks like this:

```
onPress={() => navigate("MessageScreen")}
```

Nothing is shown. Would it be possible in any way to have the navigation from message screen to the other user screen seemless without deleting the bottom tab bar and without adding another component to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, what you're trying to do is wrong.
It makes sense that the bottomBar disappears because you use a SwitchNavigator to navigate between "AppContainer" and "OtherUser".

So the moment you navigate to "OtherUser", you are no longer in a bottomMenu navigation, you are simply in a SwitchNavigator!

To be able to do what you want to do, you should integrate a stackNavigator instead of MessageScreen,
then in this StackNavigator, you integrate your MessageScreen as well as OtherUser

Currently, your navigation seems to be like this:

```
- Loading
- App
  -- bottomTabMenu
     -- Home
     -- Message
     -- Posts
     -- Notifications
     -- Profile
- Auth
- OtherUser
```

So as you see, when you go to "OtherUser" you are not in a BottomMenu navigation anymore, besides that, you can't go back because actually, to be able to go back with a back button, you need to be in a stack navigation.

So if you want to be able to go to the user profile from your messageScreen, you need to wrap it in a navigation stack, and integrate this stack into your bottomMenu.

Your navigation should then look something like this:

```
- Loading
- App
  -- bottomTabMenu
     -- Home
     -- Message
        -- Stack Navigation
           -- Message Screen (defaultRoute)
           -- OtherUser Screen
     -- Posts
     -- Notifications
     -- Profile
- Auth
```

So your code will be something like this:

```js
const MessageStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
           Message: MessageScreen,
           OtherUser: OtherUserScreen
      },
      {
           initialRouteName: "Message"
      }
)

default: createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        ...
        Message: {
          screen: MessageStack,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name="ios-chatboxes" size={24} color={tintColor} />,
            OtherUser: { screen: OtherUserScreen } //Delete this line, the navigationOptions are only used to define styles or behaviors on the navigation.
          }
        },
        ...
      }
```

I hope I understood the question and that this answer will help you!

Viktor

Comment: Hey Viktor, I truly appreciate you taking your valuable time in helping me with this problem. Your answer was the best I could find on the internet, and I could not thank you more, as you saved me loads of time. If I would give you a cake if I could. Thank you once again! -Gary